# Exception thrown if Part is closed from PartStack within Area

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

I have RCP application based on compatibility layer.
In UI I have Area(which contains Part Stack) like shown in below image.

[image: Application description]

I created one Part which opens in above Area, see below.
[image]

Now the problem is when I close my part, part is closing but i'm getting following Exception.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2014-01-21 14:50:02.377
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/ui/UIElement/toBeRendered/SET] to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler@88c615
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElementsRecursive(ModelServiceImpl.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.findElements(ModelServiceImpl.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.unzoomSharedArea(WorkbenchPage.java:5132)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.unzoomSharedArea(WorkbenchPage.java:5153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$13(WorkbenchPage.java:5151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchPage.java:5197)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.hidePart(PartServiceImpl.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.closePart(StackRenderer.java:1069)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.access$5(StackRenderer.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer$11.close(StackRenderer.java:945)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at com.infineon.scm.Application.start(Application.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

**Its works (No Exception in following case):**

1. If I remove Area and only use PartStack then It works and i'm not getting any Exception.
2. Even in my application I'm reusing JSDT perspective, if I'm open same part in JSDT's Editor Area and if I close it then also it works(No Exception).

Is something I'm missing.?

Comment: Sounds similar to Eclipse bug [400185](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=400185)

Answer (score 0):

The MArea was implemented with supporting a shared 'editor' area in Eclipse 4 and may well have some logical holes in it for other uses, especially if there are no perspectives (is this the case?).